# Multiplying a TextView and an EditText together and displaying in a Textview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a dynamic Textview which a number is added depending on a spinner. (id:Textview3)

I have an EditText that allows an integer input. (id:editText)

I'm looking to add these 2 values together and display it into a TextView.(id:textView4)

context: It's a food application adding an item of food depending on spinner selection then calculating total calories dependent on the weight of food imputed.

All advise welcomed, Thanks in advance!

```
     public class AddActivity extends Activity implements               OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        spinner1 = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.spinner01);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.spinner02);

        chooseCategory();
        chooseBreakfast();
        chooseLunch();
        chooseDinner();
        chooseSnack();


    }

    static Spinner spinner1, spinner2 = null;

    public void chooseCategory() {

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> catAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.foodtype, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        catAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(catAdapter);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new planOnSelectedListener());
    }

    public void chooseBreakfast() {

        ArrayAdapter<Food> planAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new Food[]{
                new Food(1, "Toast"),
                new Food(99, "Cereal"),
                new Food(53, "Fruit"),
                new Food(153, "Yogurt")
        });

        spinner2.setAdapter(planAdapter1);
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        Button button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button01);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void chooseLunch() {
        ArrayAdapter<Food> planAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new Food[]{
                new Food(1, "Sandwich"),
                new Food(99, "Wrap"),
                new Food(53, "Salad"),
        });

        spinner2.setAdapter(planAdapter2);
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        Button button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button01);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void chooseDinner() {
        ArrayAdapter<Food> planAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new Food[]{
                new Food(1, "Pizza"),
                new Food(99, "Pasta"),
                new Food(53, "Fish and Chips"),
        });

        spinner2.setAdapter(planAdapter2);
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        Button button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button01);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void chooseSnack() {
        ArrayAdapter<Food> planAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new Food[]{
                new Food(1, "Crisps"),
                new Food(99, "Chocolate"),
                new Food(53, "Donut"),
        });

        spinner2.setAdapter(planAdapter2);
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        Button button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button01);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void toastState(String prefix, Food cl) {
        if (cl != null) {
            String desc = "Event: " + prefix + "\nName: " + cl.name;
            desc += "\nCalorie: " + String.valueOf(cl.calories);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), desc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void calorieState(Food cl) {

        TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textView3.setText(String.valueOf("Item Calories: " + cl.getCalorie()));

    }

    public void nameState (Food cl) {

        TextView textView6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        textView6.setText(String.valueOf("Item Name: " + cl.getName()));

    }

    public class planOnSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {
            parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);

            if (pos == 0) {
                chooseBreakfast();
            } else if (pos == 1) {
                chooseLunch();
            } else if (pos == 2) {
                chooseDinner();
            } else if (pos == 3) {
                chooseSnack();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }


    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Get the currently selected State object from the spinner
        Food st = (Food) spinner2.getSelectedItem();

        // Show it via a toast
        toastState("onItemSelected", st);
        calorieState(st);
        nameState(st);

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Get the currently selected State object from the spinner
        Food st = (Food) spinner2.getSelectedItem();
        toastState("onClick", st);

    }
}
```

Comment: where is `editText` and `Textview3` ?

Comment: in activity_main.xml... i'm looking for advice before i start implementing changes to what i already have working. editText is food weight and textView3 is the calories taken in calorieState()

Comment: final EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        final double A = Double.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());
        final double B = Double.valueOf(textView.getText().toString());
        double result = A*B;
        textView1.setText(String.valueOf(result)); 
Something along these lines in my OnClick?